# Does VB.Net have anything equivalent to the "THIS" method

Tags: javascript, vb.net

In javascript you can use the word "this" to reference the current control that you are working with.  Does VB.net have something similar?

For instance take the following call to a global subroutine:

```
pubsubButtonCall(Me, Button1)
```

Where "ME" is the current form and BUtton1 is a button on the form.  What I would like to do is replace the Button1, which is an actual button and replace it with something that signifies the current button that was clicked.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: In the button's click event handler, there is a `sender` parameter that is the control that was actually clicked.

Comment: `this` does not reference the current control you are working with. It represents the current *object* that is bound to `this` and can change per method call. The closest thing I can think of is `Me` when you are working in terms of objects in VB.NET. That said, @ChrisDunaway is probably going to give you a good solution for what you want.

Comment: thanks sender worked